# Dbpedia Dump has missing Values?

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web, dbpedia, linked-data

I just downloaded some dumpfiles in `.ttl` format from http://wiki.dbpedia.org/downloads-2016-10.

Here an Overview of the files I got in my triplestore:

```
E:/virtuoso-opensource/vad/instance_types_de.ttl                                  instanceTypesDe
                        2           2018.4.30 10:3.37 155858000  2018.4.30 10:3.43 887243000  0           NULL        NULL
E:/virtuoso-opensource/vad/instance_types_en.ttl                                  instanceTypesEn
                        2           2018.4.30 12:6.25 723316000  2018.4.30 12:7.4 476533000  0           NULL        NULL
E:/virtuoso-opensource/vad/instance_types_sdtyped_dbo_de.ttl                      instanceTypesDe
                        2           2018.4.30 10:3.43 887244000  2018.4.30 10:3.45 894358000  0           NULL        NULL
E:/virtuoso-opensource/vad/instance_types_sdtyped_dbo_en.ttl                      instanceTypesEn
                        2           2018.4.30 12:7.4 476534000  2018.4.30 12:7.32 406130000  0           NULL        NULL
E:/virtuoso-opensource/vad/instance_types_transitive_de.ttl                       instanceTypesDe
                        2           2018.4.30 10:3.45 895358000  2018.4.30 10:4.16 519110000  0           NULL        NULL
E:/virtuoso-opensource/vad/instance_types_transitive_en.ttl                       instanceTypesEn
                        2           2018.4.30 12:7.32 406131000  2018.4.30 12:10.50 700472000  0           NULL        NULL
E:/virtuoso-opensource/vad/interlanguage_links_chapters_de.ttl                    LanguageLinksDe
                        2           2018.4.30 10:4.16 520110000  2018.4.30 10:5.56 986856000  0           NULL        NULL
E:/virtuoso-opensource/vad/labels_de.ttl                                          LabelsDe
                        2           2018.4.30 10:5.56 986857000  2018.4.30 10:6.45 923655000  0           NULL        NULL
```

So now i was trying to Query

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT DISTINCT *
WHERE
{
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Rappensee_Hut> ?p ?o .
}
```

That doesnt give me any results. The fact that I just imported the Instance Types shouldnt be the problem, because if you put the query from above in the live sparql Endpoints from dbpedia.org you get the type Place returned from it, as you can see here: [dbpedia Rappensee_Hut](http://dbpedia.org/page/Rappensee_Hut)

I wonder if I am missing anything.

Thanks for the Help!

Edit: I downloaded the english types to fill missing types in my german Dataset, because in the german dump, I could only find a `LanguageLink` and a `Label` from [http://de.dbpedia.org/resource/Rappenseehütte](http://de.dbpedia.org/resource/Rappenseeh%C3%BCtte) and also no type. Are there more files for `rdf:Types` in general that I'm not using?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that all the files have been loaded properly? Did you check the files itself for the triple? `grep 'Rappensee_Hut' ...` - I checked `instance_types_en.ttl` and it doesn't contain the triple.

Comment: yeh, they are loaded properly. And i dont find it in these files too. My question is rather, why is there no triple in this file? Like you see in the Link to http://dbpedia.org/page/Rappensee_Hut. You even find it with the Online Live SPARQL endpoint from dbpedia. So my question is: Why isnt the triple in the data I can download from their downloadsection?

Comment: I want to have the same data that you can use on "https://dbpedia.org/sparql"

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing here that tells us that the `rdf:type` you see on http://dbpedia.org/page/Rappensee_Hut came from any of the files you loaded.

I cannot immediately download and parse all the files in the download directory, so I cannot tell you which if any dump file holds the specific you want, nor whether you're seeing the result of some post-load process(es).

The fastest and surest way to get what's on the [public Dbpedia endpoint (currently the 2016-10 dataset)](http://dbpedia.org/sparql) is to run the [DBpedia Snapshot AMI](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B07BQKYGYQ) from OpenLink Software (my employer; maintainer of the DBpedia endpoint; producer of Virtuoso; etc.)  Alternatively, you can get what's on the public [Dbpedia-Live endpoint](http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql) with the [DBpedia Live AMI](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B012DSCFEK) (it starts with the 2016-04 dataset; you have to tell it to play all the changesets since)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I dont need the whole dbpedia dump. The problem is, that i would just need all "rdf:type dbo:Place" with specific rules on them (like no settlements, no PopulatedPlaces, ...) from the german dbpedia.
My idea was to construct the triples i need from the de.dbpedia Endpoint, but since its offline, i cant do this. So i downloaded the dumps from their homepage and these are diffrent than the ones from the Enpoints on the web.

Comment: I just found some more instance types files on the download Page from 2015. Instance Types Dbtax Dbo, Instance Types Dbtax Ext, Instance Types Lhd Dbo, Instance Types Lhd Ext. In the German files, Rappenseehütte has indeed some more information in there. rdf:type is marked as "dbo:WrittenWork"

Comment: Please note that mixing dumps from different DBpedia versions will deliver unexpected and probably undesired results. MANY changes have been made to the extractors which produced the data therein, and many corrections (especially to `rdf:type` triples) have been made in the 2016-10 dataset vs the 2016-04 dataset.

Answer (score 0):

So I found help in the Support Forum from dbpedia (http://wiki.dbpedia.org/support).
If anyone is wondering about the core files of dbpedia.org, you find them [here](http://downloads.dbpedia.org/2016-10/core/)